# How to display process with status -R

Tags: text-processing, ps

I'm trying to output all processes with `STAT` field `-R`.

I tried following command but it is not best matching.
Any other way to display??

```
ps aux |grep  R
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `r` option:

```
ps auxr
```

This limits the selection to running processes only.

Compared to post-processing the output, this has the advantage of being handled entirely within `ps`, and works even if the output doesn’t reflect the process status; for example

```
ps r -o pid,command
```